# Left hand side assignment in C# error

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am converting some VB code into C#.
In VB the code looks like the following:

```
oTP.CreateObject("SomeInterop")    
oTP.Session("SomeKey") = 5
```

In C#, if I do:

```
oTP.Session("SomeKey") = 5;
```

I get a compilation error, "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer".
In VB, oTP is declared as an object and in C#, i declared it as dynamic.
In the oTP code, Session looks like this:

```
Public Property Session(ByVal VariableName As String) As Object
Get
....
End Get
Set(ByVal Value As Object)
.....
End Set
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax for [indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) in C# is different - you need to use square braces:

```
oTP.Session["SomeKey"] = 5;
```